# Pushforward of cocartesian fibrations

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

Let $\pi : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ be a cocartesian fibration of $\infty$-categories which straightens to a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Cat}_\infty$. If $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ is another functor then the composition $F \circ G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathrm{Cat}_\infty$ unstraightens to the cocartesian fibration $\mathcal{E} \times_{\mathcal{C}} \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}$ obtained by pulling back $\pi$ along $G$.

Now let $H : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor which goes the other way. Then we can construct the left/right Kan extension $\mathrm{Kan}_H(F) : \mathcal{D} \to \mathrm{Cat}_\infty$; as a functor of $F$, this is a left/right adjoint to $H^\ast : \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{D}, \mathrm{Cat}_\infty) \to \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}, \mathrm{Cat}_\infty)$. What does $\mathrm{Kan}_G(F)$ functor unstraighten to, in terms of $\pi$? More precisely, does $- \times_{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{C} : \mathrm{CocartFib}(\mathcal{D}) \to \mathrm{CocartFib}(\mathcal{C})$ have an explicit left/right adjoint? Obviously it has one (of either kind): it takes $\pi$ to an unstraightening of $\mathrm{Kan}_H(F)$ (left or right). Can it be described explicitly in terms of $\pi$ itself, without appealing to the straightening/unstraightening equivalence?

Comment: In Gepner-Haugseng-Nikolaus (a paper called "Lax limits ...." , I can find the precis reference) they describe a left adjoint to the inclusion of cocartesian functors over $C$ into all functors over $C$. If you combine this with the "naive guess" that one can come up with using un/straightening, you can come up with a formula. If no one answers first, I'll try to write it down in more detail later ! (I was wondering about the very same thing a couple of months ago :D)

Comment: I checked the paper: after dualizing, there is a functor $\mathrm{Free} : (\mathrm{Cat}_\infty)_{/\mathcal{C}} \to \mathrm{Cocart}(\mathcal{C})$ which sends $\mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{K} \times_{\mathcal{C}} \mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ where the pullback is taken along the source map and the projection is the target map. Using my notation above, my first guess would be that $\mathrm{Free}(H \circ -) : \mathrm{Cocart}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathrm{Cocart}(\mathcal{D})$ is the desired left adjoint. When I try to straighten this, however, I get something...

Comment: ... which I am not sure evaluates to the left Kan extension (which is what it should be). What do you mean by "combine" with the naive guess?

Comment: The point is that if you simply take $Free(H\circ -)$, you get, instead of the formula for left Kan extensions with colimits over slices, a formula with *lax* colimits over slices (or maybe oplax). So to make up for it, you're supposed to invert a bunch of arrows - which ones precisely, the formula for left Kan extension is supposed to tell you :D

Comment: so somehow my suggestion is to write down a formula for what should unstraighten $y\mapsto colim_{x\in C_{/y}} f(x)$, and to do this you notice that $Free(H\circ -)$ is not far from this, but with a lax colimit instead

Comment: The category $Psh(\Delta)$ of simplicial spaces is a topos, and in particular is locally cartesian closed. So $H^\ast$ has a right adjoint $H_\ast$ at the level of simplicial spaces, generally called the _pushforward_. You can compute it on simplices by adjointness and Yoneda. If $H$ is not an [exponentiable fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conduch%C3%A9+functor#highercategorical_versions) then $H_\ast$ does not preserve complete Segal spaces. But perhaps it does preserve co/cartesian fibrations. (A co/cartesian fibration is exponentiable, but that's not what you need.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to expand on what I wrote in the comments. I'll focus on left Kan extensions- I think the story for right Kan extensions is a bit more subtle, for reasons I'll ty to mention at the end.

A (too) naive guess is that the following can work: simply take the following composite $coCart_C \to Cat_{/C}\to Cat_{/D} \to coCart_D$ where the last functor is the left adjoint to the inclusion $coCart_D \to Cat_{/D}$.

The last functor is explicit thanks to the work of Gepner-Haugseng-Nikolaus: it is given by $(K\to D)\mapsto K\times_D Fun(\Delta^1,D)$ where the pullback is taken with respect to the source map, and the target map is used as the remaining projection.

If we look at what this composite does to $E\to C$, we see that it sends it to $E\times_D Fun(\Delta^1,D)$, and so the fiber over a given $d\in D$ is $E\times_C C\times_D D_{/d}$.

In terms of functors this is like the unstraightening of the restriction to $C\times_D D_{/d}$ of the functor classified by $E$. In other words, it classifies the functor over $C\times_D D_{/d}$ whose colimit is supposed to be the value at $d$ of the left Kan extension of (the functor classified by) $E$.

The point is that this naive guess is not correct (the total category of a cocartesian fibration is not the same as the colimit of the functor it classifies), but not *too far* from correct (the total category is not *too far* from the colimit). In fact, we know exactly how far: if $E\to K$ is a coCartesian fibration, the colimit of the functor it classifies is exactly $E[cocart^{-1}]$ . So here we have to invert the morphisms that are cocartesian *over* $C\times_D D_{/d}$.

Now we can use the following fact: given a cocartesian fibration $E\to K$, we understand pretty well how to "fiberwise" invert morphisms : we can actually invert morphisms globally as long as some basic properties are satisfied. Precisely which is explained in Hinich's paper *Dwyer-Kan localization revisited*, proposition 2.1.4  (in his notation, we should consider here $W$ to consist only of equivalences). I claim that in $E\times_D Fun(\Delta^1,D)= E\times_C C\times_D Fun(\Delta^1,D)$ the class $V$ of morphisms that are coCartesian over $C\times_D D_{/d}$ in the corresponding fiber satisfies the assumptions of Hinich's 2.1.4., and you can therefore invert them and keep a coCartesian fibration which now at least "looks" like it has the correct fibers.

This gives a functor $coCart_C\to coCart_D$ with a transformation from the original one. Combining the Gepner-Haugseng-Nikolaus universal property and the universal property of localizations as well as Hinich's analysis of which morphisms are coCartesian in the localization, you should obtain that this functor is indeed the left adjoint to pullback. If you want more detail about this proof, I can add them but for now let me leave it as an exercise :)

For right Kan extensions, it feels like the story is similar, although it now involves a *right adjoint* to the inclusion $coCart_D\to Cat_{/D}$, as well as a right adjoint to the pullback functor $Cat_{/D}\to Cat_{/C}$. I don't know of a place where the first right adjoint is explicitly described (in fact, as far as I understand, the fact that $coCart_D\to Cat_{/D}$ preserves colimits is not a very well-known fact, even though it is true) but it should be something like a category of sections, namely if $E\to D$ is an arbitrary functor, the corresponding fibration should classify $d\mapsto Fun_{/D}(D_{d/},E)$, so some category of "sections".

For the second functor, it usually doesn't exist, namely pullback only has a right adjoint when $C\to D$ is "exponentiable". So even if this works, it would work only in limited generality, so it is not as satisfying because right Kan extension always exists. But ok, let's settle for this now and assume we are in this restricted generality.

Now I haven't checked this in detail, but if you play the same game as above you should see that the "naive" guess is wrong for similar reasons, namely instead of the usual limit formula for right Kan extensions you will get a category of sections of a coCartesian fibration over $C\times_D D_{d/}$ with no conditions, and so similarly, you can correct the naive guess by adding some coCartesian-ness condition on these sections, and presumably by combining again these things you should be able to prove that what you've constructed is right adjoint to pullback.

But I checked this even less than the left Kan extension case, and as I said even if this works it would only be if $C\to D$ is exponentiable, which is quite unsatisfactory, and it would be nice to see how the story plays out in general.

Comment: I'll have to mull over it, but this detailed answer is very helpful. Thanks!